# What is known about "dimension two" vertex algebras?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, big-list, vertex-algebras

In the paper [Chiral Koszul duality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.5803), Gaitsgory and Francis develop a notion of a chiral algebra living on an arbitrary variety $X$. When $X=\mathbf{A}^1$ and the chiral algebra is translation invariant, this reproduces the usual notion of a vertex algebra.

I'm interested in getting a picture about what can/has been said about chiral algebras one dimension up, when $X$ is a surface. For instance,

- The notion of vertex algebra reappears throughout physics, e.g. in conformal field theory. Does the higher dimensional analogue appear in physics naturally?
- There is an interesting relation between loop spaces/affine Grassmannian and vertex algebras, e.g. via the WZW vertex algebra $V_k(\mathfrak{g})$. Is there any interesting relation between the higher dimensional vertex algebras and say the *double* loop space, which as I understand it is an even more interesting object?

Comment: U might want to check out the work of Faonte, Hennion and Kapranov for the Bun_{G} case. Nb that even purely local things here are derived in nature, as the authors explain in detail (punctured d disc should be derived object for d>1, get new classes in coherent cohom in dim 2d-1). In general from conversation with one of the authors above my understanding is that not much at all is known. In the physics literature I often see what seems to be something like a two dim "real" chiral algebra, where antiholomorphic coordinates are used. I don't understand at all what is going on in this case.

Comment: One thing that happens in higher dimension is that the term 'chiral' becomes increasingly inaccurate..